# Remove colors from an image if they are not in a list python

Tags: python, image, list, numpy, colors

I have a relatively large RGBA image (converted to numpy) that I need to replace all colors which do not appear in a list. How could I do this in a pythonic fast way?

Using simple iteration I have a solution to this problem, however due to the images being quite large (2500 x 2500) this process is very slow.

```
# Keep only these colors in the image, otherwise replace with (0,255,0,255)
palette = [[0,0,0,255],[0, 255, 0,255], [255, 0, 0,255], [128, 128, 128,255], [0, 0, 255,255], [255, 0, 255,255], [0, 255, 255,255], [255, 255, 255,255], [128, 128, 0,255], [0, 128, 128,255], [128, 0, 128,255]]

# Current slow solution with a 2500 x 2500 x 4 array (mask)
for z in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for y in range(mask.shape[1]):
        if (mask[z,y,:].tolist() not in palette):
            mask[z, y] = (0,255,0,255)
```

Expected operating time per image: less than half a minute

Current time: two minutes

Comment: Just a note, you are not doing recursion, you are doing iteration.

Comment: Edited, thanks @Jmonsky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely not some time windows you should be looking at. Here's an approach with `broadcasting`:

```
# palette.shape == (4,11)
palette = np.array(palette).transpose()

# sample a.shape == (2,2,4)
a= np.array([[[ 28, 231, 203, 235],
         [255, 0, 0,255]],

       [[ 50, 152,  36, 151],
        [252,  43,  63,  25]]])

# mask
# all(2) force all channels to be equal
# any(-1) matches any color
mask = (a[:,:,:, None] == palette).all(2).any(-1)

# replace color
rep_color = np.array([0,255,0,255])

# np.where to the rescue:
ret = np.where(mask[:,:,None], a, rep_color[None,None,:])
```

The sample:

[image]

becomes

[image]

and for `a = np.random.randint(0,256, (2500,2500,4))`, it takes:

> 5.26 s ± 179 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

Update: if you forces everything to be `np.uint8` you can merge the channels to an `int32` and get even faster speed:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,256, (2500,2500,4), dtype=np.uint8)
p = np.array(palette, dtype=np.uint8).transpose()

# zip the data into 32 bits
# could be even faster if we handle the memory directly
aa = a[:,:,0] * (2**24) + a[:,:,1]*(2**16) + a[:,:,2]*(2**8) + a[:,:,3]
pp = p[0]*(2**24) + p[1]*(2**16) + p[2]*(2**8) + p[3]
mask = (aa[:,:,None]==pp).any(-1)
ret = np.where(mask[:,:,None], a, rep_color[None,None,:])
```

which takes:

> 1.34 s ± 29.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Very nice answer 

Answer (score 2):

i had a go with [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/). This is a threaded, streaming image processing library, so it's fast and doesn't need much memory.

```
import sys
import pyvips
from functools import reduce

# Keep only these colors in the image, otherwise replace with (0,255,0,255)
palette = [[0,0,0,255], [0, 255, 0,255], [255, 0, 0,255], [128, 128, 128,255], [0, 0, 255,255], [255, 0, 255,255], [0, 255, 255,255], [255, 255, 255,255], [128, 128, 0,255], [0, 128, 128,255], [128, 0, 128,255]]

im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access="sequential")

# test our image against each sample ... bandand() will AND all image bands
# together, ie. we want pixels where they all match
masks = [(im == colour).bandand() for colour in palette]

# OR all the masks together to find pixels which are in the palette
mask = reduce((lambda x, y: x | y), masks)

# pixels not in the mask become [0, 255, 0, 255]
im = mask.ifthenelse(im, [0, 255, 0, 255])

im.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

With a 2500x 2500 pixel PNG on this 2015 i5 laptop I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./replace-pyvips.py ~/pics/x.png y.png
55184:0.92
```

So a max of 55mb of memory, and 0.92s of elapsed time.

I tried Quang Hoang's excellent numpy version for comparison:

```
p = np.array(palette).transpose()

# mask
# all(2) force all channels to be equal
# any(-1) matches any color 
mask = (a[:,:,:, None] == p).all(2).any(-1)

# replace color
rep_color = np.array([0,255,0,255])

# np.where to the rescue:
a = np.where(mask[:,:,None], a, rep_color[None,None,:])

im = Image.fromarray(a.astype('uint8'))
im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Run on the same 2500 x 2500 pixel image:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./replace-broadcast.py ~/pics/x.png y.png
413504:3.08
```

A peak of 410MB of memory, and 3.1s elapsed.

Both versions could be sped up further by comparing uint32, as Hoang says.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code I was able to substitute a randomly generated image of 2500 x 2500 anywhere between 33 to 37 seconds. The method you had took my machine on between 51 to 57 seconds to execute.

```py
mask = np.random.rand(2500,2500,4)
mask = np.floor(mask * 255)

palette = np.array([[0,0,0,255],[0, 255, 0,255], [255, 0, 0,255], [128, 128, 128,255], [0, 0, 255,255], [255, 0, 255,255], [0, 255, 255,255], [255, 255, 255,255], [128, 128, 0,255], [0, 128, 128,255], [128, 0, 128,255]])
default = np.array([0,255,0,255])
for z in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for y in range(mask.shape[1]):
        if not mask[z,y,:] in palette:
            mask[z,y,:] = default
```